# How are the names of model items not showing up in DJango Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-model-field

I'm building a website using python and Django, but when I looked in the admin, the names of the model items aren't showing up.
[image]

[image]

So, the objects that I am building in the admin aren't showing their names.
admin.py:

```
from .models import Article, Author

# Register your models here.
@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'main_txt', 'date_of_publication']
    list_display_links = None
    list_editable = ['title', 'main_txt']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
@admin.register(Author)
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'join_date', 'email', 'phone_num']
    list_display_links = ['join_date']
    list_editable = ['email', 'phone_num', ]
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name[0]}"
```

models.py:

```
# Create your models here.

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    email = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    join_date = models.DateField()
    participated_art = models.ManyToManyField('Article', blank=True)


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date_of_publication = models.DateField()
    creaters = models.ManyToManyField('Author', blank=False)
    main_txt = models.TextField()
    notes = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method in the model itself instead of admin.py, so:

```py
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    email = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    join_date = models.DateField()
    participated_art = models.ManyToManyField('Article', blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date_of_publication = models.DateField()
    creaters = models.ManyToManyField('Author', blank=False)
    main_txt = models.TextField()
    notes = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

You need  to specify a `def __str__(self)` method.
Example:

```
class Author(models..):
    ....


    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

Comment: Which file is it in?

Comment: models.py, as you can see by the `Author(models...)`

Comment: @nigel239: I would advise to use string formatting, for example with an f-string. If `self.first_name` is for example `None`, then adding `None` and a `str`ing will raise an error.

Comment: It cannot be saved with a Nonetype in this example.